# Retrieving Values From a Prepared Statement and Select Query in Go

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I'm unsure how to retrieve values from a prepared statement since result only returns information about the transaction.

```
statement, err := txn.Prepare(`SELECT id, password FROM public.user WHERE email = $1`)
result, err = stmt.Exec(email, password, email)
```

I understand Query() and QueryRow() have the intended result, but from what I understand, they are unsafe. Any help on this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are perfectly safe, you use it the same way, exec is really just for inserts:

```
stmt, err := txn.Prepare(`SELECT id, password FROM public.user WHERE email = $1`)
rows, err := stmt.Query(email)
```

Check: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SQLInterface

Comment: Seems that `Exec()` should be also used for `DELETE` commands as well, instead of `Query()`, stated at http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html